# Web service input into SQL query into R in Azure ML

Tags: web-services, azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I have the following simple setup in Azure ML. [image: ML setup] 
Basically the Reader is a SQL query to a DB which returns a vector called Pdelta, which is then passed to the R script for further processing  and the results are then returned back to the web service. The DB query is simple (`SELECT Pdelta FROM ...`) and it works fine. I have set the DB query as a web service paramater as well.

Everything seems to work fine, but at the end when i publish it as a web service and test it, it somehow asks for an additional input parameter. The additional parameter gets called `PDELTA`.
[image]

I am wondering why is this happening, what is it that I am overlooking? I would like to make this web service ask for only one parameter - the SQL query (Delta Query) which would then deliver the Pdeltas.

Any ideas or suggestions would be grealty appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the web service input block and publish the web service without it. That way the Pdelta input will be passed in only from the Reader module.

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem. My mistake was assuming that the web service wouldn't work without the web service input.